# SSH tunnel created successfully, but telnet test still fails

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I am on a RHEL 5 system, connecting to another RHEL 5 system. I created a SSH tunnel with the following command: **ssh -2 -4 -f -x -N -L 1527:remote_host:1527 user@remote_host**

(remote_host is the same server)

I type the password, and I'm immediately returned to the command prompt. I run a quick 'ps axu | grep ssh' to verify and see a process for the ssh command I just executed:

```
dashbrd  17861  0.0  0.1  68796 13224 ?        Ss   12:44   0:00 ssh -2 -4 -f -x -N -L 1527:remote_host:1527 user@remote_host
```

I assume my tunnel is established successfully.

Then I test using 'telnet remote_host 1527' but that fails to connect; just hangs for several minutes before I kill it. I try the telnet test with different users on the local host (including the username I used to establish the tunnel) and the result is the same - no connection.

The purpose of this tunnel is to connect to an Oracle Listener. So, I run the **tnsping** utility; that also fails to connect. (And yes, I have the database connect configured correctly in the tnsnames.ora file.)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Voted this up because I've seen a lot of people make this mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You don't telnet to remote_host, you telnet to localhost.  If you could telnet directly to remote_host you wouldn't need a port *forward*.

```
telnet localhost 1527
```

From the ssh man page:

> ```
>  -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
>          Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be
>          forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.  This
>          works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local side,
>          optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a con-
>          nection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over
>          the secure channel, and a connection is made to host port
>          hostport from the remote machine.  Port forwardings can also be
>          specified in the configuration file.  IPv6 addresses can be spec-
>          ified with an alternative syntax:
>          [bind_address/]port/host/hostport or by enclosing the address in
>          square brackets.  Only the superuser can forward privileged
>          ports.  By default, the local port is bound in accordance with
>          the GatewayPorts setting.  However, an explicit bind_address may
>          be used to bind the connection to a specific address.  The
>          bind_address of “localhost” indicates that the listening port be
>          bound for local use only, while an empty address or ‘*’ indicates
>          that the port should be available from all interfaces.
> ```

Comment: OMG duh. thank you. Kindly forget that I ever asked this question. I just tested again using localhost and it worked.